# Connect "div" and "p" with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to put text in "p" into center of my "div". My html is like this:

```
<div class="picture">  
   <img src="/sites/default/files/default_images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg" width="1080" height="1920" alt="background to view" typeof="foaf:Image">
</div>
<p class="textik"">Hello handsome.</p>
```

But i cant change html tags. I can only us CSS. Is there a way to do this? I tried some ways, but none seems to work.

Comment: No, there is no way to restructure HTML using CSS. You can center the text within the `p` tag, but you cannot move the `p` tag into the `picture` div.

Comment: This sort of thing is trivial with jQuery, should it be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this without changing the HTML is to artificially align the p tag above the div tag like so.

```
p.textik {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Adjust as needed, and test for mobile devices.

If you don't want the elements underneath to move up as well, you can use either padding-bottom to prevent this.

```
p.textik {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works, but all other elements under these two are moved up too.

Comment: @RadoInko I assumed that would be intended behavior, it's what would happen if the p was actually inside the div too. You can use `padding-bottom` to achieve this. I will edit to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, rly nice easy solution.

Comment: @RadoInko No problem. Welcome to stack overflow! Please accept my answer if you've found it correct.

Comment: @RadoInko Also, I should say, there's a probably a better solution. Why can't you put the p tag inside the div?

Comment: Thanks, cause i need to manage view in Drupal 8 and this is probably the easiest solution. I cant change html tags so easy..I know there can be better solution for drupal, but this work nice. And its just one small project, so i dont want to spend lots of time on it.

Comment: @RadoInko  Getting what you want to work across devices reliably may be more work than changing HTML tags, and if people have to work on this software going forward (they will), it'll make life easier to not have what is essentially a hack, a hack that may give somebody a headache to figure out down the road. That being said, we've all used hacks like this, and sometimes we don't regret it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you actually want to make the `p` tag appear in the centre of your image, so you can position it `absolute` and transform it's location using css. By using `absolute` positioning and transforming the location you don't need to reposition should the size of your image/outer elements change. Something like:

```
<div class='someOuterElement'>
  <div class="picture">  
     <img src="http://placehold.it/500/500" width="500" height="500" >
  </div>
  <p class='textik'>Hello handsome.</p>
</div>
```

and style it with:

```
.someOuterElement {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px
}

.textik {
  text-align; center;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

There's more info about css transform [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: This looks good and it doesnt mess up other elements too. I will do some test but looks great, thanks!